# What are the attributes of 'urlretrieve' function in Python?

Tags: python

I want to write a Python program to automatically fill web forms. On searching a lot, i found this code.

`import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.google.com/", "somefile.html", lambda x,y,z:0, urllib.urlencode({"username": "xxx", "password": "pass"}))`

This function takes a lot of arguments. Can you please explain what each argument means?

Comment: read the doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take a look at the [official Python documentation for `urllib.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve), we get a nice explanation:

> Copy a network object denoted by a URL to a local file, if necessary.
>   If the URL points to a local file, or a valid cached copy of the
>   object exists, the object is not copied. Return a tuple `(filename,
>   headers)` where `filename` is the local file name under which the object
>   can be found, and `headers` is whatever the `info()` method of the object
>   returned by `urlopen()` returned (for a remote object, possibly cached).
>   Exceptions are the same as for `urlopen()`.
>
> The second argument, if present, specifies the file location to copy
>   to (if absent, the location will be a tempfile with a generated name).
>   The third argument, if present, is a hook function that will be called
>   once on establishment of the network connection and once after each
>   block read thereafter. The hook will be passed three arguments; a
>   count of blocks transferred so far, a block size in bytes, and the
>   total size of the file. The third argument may be -1 on older FTP
>   servers which do not return a file size in response to a retrieval
>   request.
>
> If the url uses the http: scheme identifier, the optional data
>   argument may be given to specify a `POST` request (normally the request
>   type is `GET`). The data argument must in standard
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded format; see the `urlencode()` function
>   below.
>
> Changed in version 2.5: `urlretrieve()` will raise `ContentTooShortError`
>   when it detects that the amount of data available was less than the
>   expected amount (which is the size reported by a Content-Length
>   header). This can occur, for example, when the download is
>   interrupted.
>
> The Content-Length is treated as a lower bound: if there’s more data
>   to read, `urlretrieve()` reads more data, but if less data is available,
>   it raises the exception.
>
> You can still retrieve the downloaded data in this case, it is stored
>   in the content attribute of the exception instance.
>
> If no Content-Length header was supplied, `urlretrieve()` can not check
>   the size of the data it has downloaded, and just returns it. In this
>   case you just have to assume that the download was successful.

By the way, they're called arguments or parameters, not attributes.